# Collsioin Detection of Javascript 2d Box

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I am trying to make a program over the weekend in JavaScript using the canvas element that makes a black box move around the screen in random directions using a series of `if statement` when it hits the limits of the box, I would like it to bounce back in another random direction.

The code below makes the program I described above, but after a while it the box will disappear when it hits a side after a while. I have tried everything I could, but the problem still persists. Something that is notable is that it usally disappears when it hits the right side, or the bottom side. Also, the box will continue to move after it disappears, (I figured this out by expanding the canvas) almost as if the `if statement` did not even work.

The code:

```
<DOCTYPE. html>
<html>
<title>Moving Box</title>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<script>
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var box = function(x,y){

this.x = x;
this.y = y;

var min = 0;
var max = 1000;


var corner = false;

var dirx;
var diry;
var corner; 

var rand = function(){
return Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
}

var change = function(){
var choice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);

if(choice == 1){
  return -1;
}


if(choice == 2){
  return 1;
}

}

this.draw = function(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,1920,1080);
  ctx.fillRect(x,y,20,20);

  //tests corners
  if(x == min && y == min){
    dirx = rand();
    diry = rand();
    corner = true;
  } else if(x == max && y == max){
    dirx = rand() * -1;
    diry = rand() * -1;
    corner = true;
  } else if(x == max && y == min){
    dirx = rand() * -1;
    diry = rand();
    corner = true;
  } else if(x == min && y == max){
    dirx = rand();
    diry = rand() * -1;
    corner = true;
  } else {
    corner = false;
  }

  //tests sides

  if(y == min && corner == false){ //top side
    diry = rand();
    dirx = rand() * change();
  } else if(x == max && corner == false){ //right side
    dirx = rand() * -1;
    diry = rand() * change();
  } else if(y == max && corner == false){ //bottom side 
    diry = rand() * -1;
    dirx = rand();
  } else if(x == min && corner == false){ //left side
    dirx = rand();
    diry = rand() * change();
}


y = y + diry;
x = x + dirx;
}
}

Box = new box(0, 1000);

setInterval( function() {

Box.draw();

}, 1);

</script>
</html>
```

The `change()` function simply gives a +1 or -1 to change directions to make it look more random.

Answer (score 1):

Check for greater than(or less than) in addition to equal to in your test checks. Not just top == min etc. Do top >= min for example